# How to fix "Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError" error while installing packages using pip where a file METADATA was not found?

Tags: python, pip

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~ip-19.0.1.dist-info/METADATA'

I am getting this error each time I am trying to install a package using pip3 for python3.7 in macOS(Mojave). The file resides in the directory but it still says no such file.

I have tried solutions that I found on stackoverflow. I have tried using sudo; --user; uninstalling and installing six like :

> sudo pip3 install pandas
>
> sudo -H pip3 install --user virtualenv
>
> pip3 install pandas --no-cache-dir
>
> pip3 install --force-reinstall -U --no-binary :all: six

None of the above proved to be useful.Each of these gave the same error. I am not able to setup python properly due to these issues.

This is the stack of my tries and their result.

> [PALLAVIs-MacBook-Air:/ pallavi$ pip3 install scikit-learn
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py:339: UserWarning: Unbuilt egg for Unknown [unknown version] (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
>     self.satisfied_by = pkg_resources.get_distribution(str(no_marker))
>   Collecting scikit-learn 
>   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/0f/e2279fee7f9834c63b24fe64515412fd21dd81e82adcf6c79dcc93bb8e6a/scikit_learn-0.20.2-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (7.8MB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 7.8MB 688kB/s 
>   Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.13.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.2.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.16.1)
>   Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~ip-19.0.1.dist-info/METADATA'
>
> PALLAVIs-MacBook-Air:/ pallavi$ sudo -H pip3 install virtualenv
>   Password:
>   Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (16.3.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from virtualenv) (40.6.3)
>   Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~ip-19.0.1.dist-info/METADATA'
>
> PALLAVIs-MacBook-Air:/ pallavi$ sudo -H pip3 install --user virtualenv
>   Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (16.3.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from virtualenv) (40.6.3)
>   Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~ip-19.0.1.dist-info/METADATA'
>
> PALLAVIs-MacBook-Air:/ pallavi$ pip3 install pandas --no-cache-dir
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py:339: UserWarning: Unbuilt egg for Unknown [unknown version] (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages)
>     self.satisfied_by = pkg_resources.get_distribution(str(no_marker))
>   Collecting pandas
>   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/7d/90cb0a6e4b62efb2078e4e377f0fb162237f341df02ff4310b178d576bd8/pandas-0.24.0-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (15.9MB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 15.9MB 1.5MB/s 
>   Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2.7.5)
>   Collecting pytz>=2011k (from pandas)
>     Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/28/1d3920e4d1d50b19bc5d24398a7cd85cc7b9a75a490570d5a30c57622d34/pytz-2018.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510kB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 512kB 666kB/s 
>   Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.12.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (1.16.1)
>   Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas)
>     Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~ip-19.0.1.dist-info/METADATA'

Comment: Can you run `pip3 --version` and `python3 --version`..? Do these versions match?

Comment: Hey listen..Thanks for your time.
Yes, those versions matched. But I couldn't find a solution. For now, I have moved onto Anaconda .

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54778630/10682164.

Comment: @totalhack - not a duplicate. The issue there is path-too-long.

Comment: @Elazar it seems to be a symptom with multiple potential causes. Path-too-long did not solve it for me or for some other folks there. For those coming from Google when searching by error message, it is a **possible** duplicate.

Comment: @totalhack agreed.