# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory \\METADATA

Tags: python, pip, conda

I relatively new to coding so I am not (yet) running virtual environments. Rather, I am just downloading packages with pip straight to my pc to run python 3.7 in atom.

When I tried to use pip the other day to install the scrapy package like so `-m pip install --user scrapy`

I got this error: `Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\adrian\\appdata\\roaming\\python\\python37\\site-packages\\pip-19.0.1.dist-info\\METADATA'`

Most of the other answers I have seen on related errors had people use conda to install some type of fix I think? When I tried to use conda to execute one of the fixes I recieved a CondaHTTPError: `SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/free/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.`

Any direction would be heartily appreciated :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip cannot find metadata file - EnvironmentError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54552367/pip-cannot-find-metadata-file-environmenterror)

Comment: I added an alternative approach to the first duplicate listed here that may work for some folks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58082184/10682164

Answer (score 87):

**TL;DR:**

Problem: Long install path

Solution 1: Install the desired python package (in my case tensorflow) in the folder which has a shorter path (for example `C:/my_py_packages/some_package`)

Solution 2: Set the registry value `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem@LongPathsEnabled` to `1` [as mentioned here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/windows.html#removing-the-max-path-limitation).

---

**Original answer:**
I got here by having this kind of error when I tried installing `tensorflow` library. My error was the following:

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\moj
> ifajlovi\faks\11master\1semestar\siap-sistemizaistrazivanjeianalizupodataka_(datamining)\projek
> at\rad\venvs\siap_venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\line
> ar_optimizer\python\utils\**pycache**\sharded_mutable_dense_hashtable.cpython-37.pyc'

So, there was no `sharded_mutable_dense_hashtable.cpython-37.pyc` file in the `__pycache__` directory. But, `sharded_mutable_dense_hashtable.cpython-37.pyc` file  was in the `utils` directory (which is the parent directory of `__pycache__` directory).

That's why I tried manually copying the `sharded_mutable_dense_hashtable.cpython-37.pyc` file in the `__pycache__` directory. When I tried that, I had a copy error which stated that the path was too long, so it couldn't put the file in the directory.

So, **the solution**:

Install the desired python package (in my case tensorflow) in the folder which has a shorter path (for example `C:/my_py_packages/some_package`) or set the registry value `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem@LongPathsEnabled` to `1` [as mentioned here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/windows.html#removing-the-max-path-limitation).

Comment: As another option you could enable support of long file names in Windows 10 by changing HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled registry value.

Comment: The same error message can bite you when you pip install pytorch after getting python from Microsoft Store. +1 since your post got me onto the root cause "path too long", see https://www.reddit.com/r/pytorch/comments/c6cllq/issue_installing_pytorch/

Comment: @DmitrySobolev Thank you for the easy and useful option. I am using Windows 7 and I just checked and didn't find the LongPathsEnabled registry in FileSystem registry folder.

Comment: I'd put the regedit solution as a tl;dr right at the start of the answer. I've almost skipped it here, and it's the right answer.

Comment: @Elazar - I added a TL;DR.

Comment: second solution worked for me. run the registry as administrator if needed

Comment: in order to install the package in another loaction, you can use --target flag, e.g:
pip3 install --upgrade --target="C:\Users\<user>\<packagename>" <packagename>
if you get an error: "ERROR: Can not combine '--user' and '--target'" you can add "--no-user" flag at the end

Comment: This can be done by running `Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" -Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1`

Answer (score 69):

This is what I did:

I could not install my python package due to this error
`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\banipreet\\anaconda3\\envs\\env-gpu\\lib\\site-packages\\requests-2.24.0.dist-info\\METADATA'`

I simply removed this folder
`'c:\\users\\banipreet\\anaconda3\\envs\\env-gpu\\lib\\site-packages\\requests-2.24.0.dist-info`
and retried `pip install my-package`, and it installed the package sucessfully.

Comment: LongPathsEnabled didn't work for me, but this did. Thanks

Comment: LongPathsEnabled didn't work for me as well.
I was able to install packages using 'conda install -c conda-forge <my_package>' still there were some packages for which I needed pip to get them installed.
You saved my day, nothing worked but this worked for me. Huge thanks!

Comment: Nothing worked for me but this solution. I wasted a few hours trying to solve it, can't believe the solution is so simple.

Comment: Longpathsenabled didn't work but this solution did work, even though some packages had dependency conflicts.

Comment: Yes! Removing folder worked for me! Thanks :))

Comment: worked for me as well.

Comment: Also worked for me. Thanks.
The directory pip was pointing to, didn't have the file METADATA, but the other folder with different version had it.

Answer (score 26):

Remove the 260 Character Path Limit by Editing the Registry, change LongPathsEnabled to 1, the regedit path in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
```

[image]

finally: restart your computer, or logout!

Comment: Because Windows.

Comment: is it save to do this, do I have to expect bugs?

Comment: interestingly I didn't need to logout or restart

Answer (score 14):

First To Access The System Registry:

1. Click Start, and then click Run.
2. In the Open box, paste %systemroot%\syswow64\regedit , and then click OK.

Then do the following below as mentioned by [Filip Savic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55189256/5826992) and [dayudodo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60750241/5826992):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem@LongPathsEnabled to 1
```

Comment: Thank you @David, I really needed to find a way in order to go through the selected answer by @Filip!!

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error trying to install Jupyter, with the path under my user profile ending with \site-packages\pip-19.0.1.dist-info\METADATA

When I checked that location it didnt contain METADATA, but another folder named pip-19.0.1.dist-info  That folder had several files in it including METADATA

I moved those files back the directory so it matched the path listed in the error and then upgraded pip (Under an administrator account)

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Which worked and updated pip

I could then run the Jupyter install and got no error

Answer (score 6):

So the above so called solution didn't make much sense to me.. Sorter path?? Anyways, what worked for me, is this.

My error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\MYUSERNAME\\appdata\\roaming\\python\\python37\\site-packages\\pip-19.0.1.dist-info\\METADATA'
```

So I went to the directory:

```
c:\\users\\MYUSERNAME\\appdata\\roaming\\python\\python37\\site-packages\\pip-19.0.1.dist-info\\
```

Indeed there was no MetaData file. However there was a folder called `19.0.1.dist-info`, inside that, has the meta data file. Just move it outside into the above directory, and BAM! Problem fixed.

Comment: Copying the METADATA file from my pipxxx.dist-info folder into the requests-xx folder worked for me (After changing the max_path as suggested elsewhere which didn't work)

Answer (score 6):

I experienced this error while I was installing Apache Superset on Windows 10. The problem is with the **MAX_PATH** length.

`pip` on windows is not able to handle those long installation path url so it usually results in errors.

**Solution:**
What worked for me was to **Uninstall** python then **ReInstalled** it again but this time after a successful reinstallation, you **HAVE TO DISABLE THE PATH LENGTH LIMIT**

[image: Like on the highlighted region there.]

Answer (score 6):

The file path is to long, open a PowerShell prompt as an administrator and run:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" -Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem while trying to install pytest on macOS

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/<USERNAME>/Projects/venvs/<VIRTUALENV_NAME>/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest-6.2.5.dist-info/METADATA
```

I navigated to the `site-packages` directory and deleted `pytest-6.2.5.dist-info` folder.
Then try running the package installation command again.

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into a similar problem with but with different versions.
Similar to what EsCS69 said I just found the director and saw that there was no MetaData file. However I couldn't just pull it out from another file. So instead I justed deleted  that folder and ran `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow-gpu`or `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow` if you aren't using the gpu version. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

**Windows 10**

Windows limits locations paths with more than 260 characters. You should just enable that following this 4 steps!!!

1. Click Window key and type `gpedit. msc`, then press the Enter key.
2. Navigate to `Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem`.
3. Double click `Enable NTFS long paths`.
4. Select Enabled, then click `OK`.

Answer (score 1):

You might not like this answer, but what worked for me was to find the file: "METADATA" from a folder with an older version and copy it into the newer one. 
This is not a solution I'm confident in, but pip at least finished installing.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the package in envs/$env_name/Lib/site-packages

Answer (score 1):

I ended up deleting the whole directory and re-running "pip install ..." and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the folder `\site-packages\` and delete the package folder you're trying to install.

Then launch `Windows PowerShell (run as admin)` and enter this command:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" `
-Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
```

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Long install path value to 1 did NOT solve problem in my case. I have removed the local folder which is giving an error and installed the package again and it worked.

Following is the error I have seen:
:ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy-1.20.1.dist-info\METADATA'

I removed the folder:
"'c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy-1.20.1.dist-info'

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked is running the same command 3 times. Don't know why, but it solved the issue.

First time
[image]

Second Time
[image]

Third time's a charm :)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

its very simple
when we get this error, this case
`Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\adrian\\appdata\\roaming\\python\\python37\\site-packages\\pip-19.0.1.dist-info\\METADATA'` . what we need to do is delete that folder , in this case  `pip-19.0.1.dist-info` ;

Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

A simple pip upgrade did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got the similar error when I was trying to install `tensorflow` on `windows: 10`. I was able to solve this by opening the `Powershell` as an `Adiminstrator` an paste the following command and click `[ENTER]`

```bash
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" `
-Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
```

I got this solution [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=powershell#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this no metadata error when I was trying to install anything, however I had the metadata.json fine in the requested directory. **I simply removed .json extension and renamed file to METADATA.**

I have macOS, so the LongPath was not the problem for me and I also could not afford to simply remove the envs directory with so many libraries installed there

Answer (score 0):

here is what helped me personally:

1. open terminal with elevated priviliges:
   in windows you can right-click on the windows symbol, open " Windows Powershell (Admin) "
2. enable long directory/path commands usinf command:
   New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" -Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
3. open your project/environment and open terminal/shell:

uninstall the library/package:

```
pip uninstall package_name
```

then reinstall it:

```
pip install package_name
```

you can use pip3 or pip3.10 based on your version of python