# OSError at / SavedModel file does not exist at: model.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Tags: django, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

```
    model=load_model("model.h5")
```

Anybody help to overcome this error while adding a saved neural network model in Django.

Comment: Is your model file placed in django's root folder? If not, give it an absolute path

Comment: yes it is in root folder

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61699140/oserror-savedmodel-file-does-not-exist-at-dnn-mpg-model-h5-saved-model-pbt . See if it helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: ../dnn/mpg\_model.h5/{saved\_model.pbtxt|saved\_model.pb}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61699140/oserror-savedmodel-file-does-not-exist-at-dnn-mpg-model-h5-saved-model-pbt)