# "errorMessage": "SavedModel file does not exist at: /mnt/efs/packages/g3s_p2_model_dnn.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}"

Tags: keras, lambda, deep-learning, model, serverless

i saved model at efs ( i mount it and successly read files in efs )
and want to load at lambda

i put ~.h5 at /mnt/efs/packages/ but why this message occured?

this is error message

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "SavedModel file does not exist at: /mnt/efs/packages/g3s_p2_model_dnn.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}",
  "errorType": "OSError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 219, in lambda_handler\n    pred_instance_dict = model_validation()\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 202, in model_validation\n    test_y, pred_y, test_data, mape = train_test_model(\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 166, in train_test_model\n    model_dnn = tf.keras.models.load_model(f'/mnt/efs/packages/g3s_p2_model_dnn.h5')\n",
    "  File \"/mnt/efs/packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py\", line 206, in load_model\n    return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)\n",
    "  File \"/mnt/efs/packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py\", line 121, in load\n    meta_graph_def = loader_impl.parse_saved_model(path).meta_graphs[0]\n",
    "  File \"/mnt/efs/packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py\", line 113, in parse_saved_model\n    raise IOError(\n"
  ]
}
```

this is code
anch=ANCHOR_INSTANCE.split(".")[0]
pred=pred_instance.split(".")[0]

```
 # save
 model_dnn.save(f'{anch}_{pred}_model_dnn.h5')
 filename = f'{anch}_{pred}_model_rfr.bin'
 pickle.dump(model_rfr, open(filename, 'wb')) 
 filename2 = f'{anch}_{pred}_model_simple.bin'
 pickle.dump(model_simple, open(filename2, 'wb'))


# load
model_dnn = load_model(f'{anch}_{pred}_model_dnn.h5')=
filename= f'{anch}_{pred}_model_rfr.bin'
model_rfr = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))  
filename2= f'{anch}_{pred}_model_simple.bin'
model_simple = pickle.load(open(filename2, 'rb'))
```

Comment: Have you installed `h5py` package?

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61699140/oserror-savedmodel-file-does-not-exist-at-dnn-mpg-model-h5-saved-model-pbt

Comment: i installed h5py package already ㅠㅠ