# I have a problem on installing tensorflow to vs code

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code

this is the error i got

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages\\tensorboard_plugin_wit\\_vendor\\tensorflow_serving\\sources\\storage_path\\__pycache__\\file_system_storage_path_source_pb2.cpython-38.pyc'
```

before that i have this error as well, but i just cut the file in to the directory.

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages\\tensorflow_estimator\\python\\estimator\\canned\\linear_optimizer\\python\\utils\\__pycache__\\sharded_mutable_dense_hashtable.cpython-38.pyc'
```

but now i can't use the same method to deal with the upper version, anyone can help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778630/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2-no-such-file-or

Comment: the first problem i found the method form that post, but the upper problem i can't deal with it