# I can't install tensorflow on win10

Tags: python, tensorflow, environment

I can't install tensorflow
I commanded pip3 install tensorflow --user and result is

> `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\kosh9\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages\\tensorboard_plugin_wit\\_vendor\\tensorflow_serving\\sources\\storage_path\\__pycache__\\file_system_storage_path_source_pb2.cpython-38.pyc'`

Namely, I could not install packages due to an Environment Error.

How could I solve this error?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778630/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2-no-such-file-or

Comment: thank you for your answer so  I have to go next step but I still have warning:  WARNING: The script tensorboard.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\kosh9\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH. so Can I Ignore this? it is okay?

Comment: This means that the path to tensorboard.exe has not been added to your system environment variables, meaning that the "tensorboard" might not be found if you execute it in the command prompt. You should try executing a tensorboard command in the command prompt; if that doesn't work, you should try [adding the full path to tensorboard.exe to you environment variables.](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing directly form PyPi.

Your on a Windows system so try one of these:

`pip install tensorflow-gpu`
or if on an Intel processor 
`pip install intel-tensorflow`

If that dons't work try to grab the `.whl` file. For Python 3.8 on windows that's:
`pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`

**Note:** You don't normally need to use `pip3` or `python3` on Windows

Comment: thx I just started programming weeks ago so I am verry newbie Can you tell me How could I learn CMD command?