# Having trouble installing PyTorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I'm having trouble installing PyTorch.

```
C:\Users\myself>pip install torch
Collecting torch
  Using cached torch-1.7.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (184.0 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\myself\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from torch) (1.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in c:\users\myself\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from torch) (3.7.4.3)
Installing collected packages: torch
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\myself\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages\\caffe2\\python\\serialized_test\\data\\operator_test\\learning_rate_adaption_op_test.test_learning_rate_adaption_op_normalization.zip'

WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.4; however, version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\myself\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

It says that I'm missing a file in caffe2, but I'm not sure how I can get that file back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Torch wheel contains caffe2 directory.

### 1.Try `--no-cache-dir` option

```
pip install --no-cache-dir torch
```

### 2. Removing the MAX_PATH Limitation

See here [3. Using Python on Windows — Python 3.7.9 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/windows.html#removing-the-max-path-limitation). You can find some more detailed discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778630/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2-no-such-file-or).

Comment: No, it didn't work. Still got the same error

Comment: [python \- Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory \\\\METADATA \- Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778630/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2-no-such-file-or)
 
Umm, have you checked this already?