# How do I solve an OSError [Errno2] no such file or directory

Tags: python, django

`C:\Users\Fabri>pip install django Requirement already satisfied: django in c:\users\fabri\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (3.2.3) ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\fabri\\appdata\\local\\packages\\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\localcache\\local-packages\\python39\\site-packages\\Django-3.2.3.dist-info\\METADATA'`

I am trying to install Django but there was a problem the first time I installed it so I uninstalled it. When trying to install it again I got back a message saying that the requirement is already fulfilled in a certain folder then it brings up an error saying that packages could not be installed because there is no such folder or directory.

Comment: can you provide the error

Comment: @Sujay Error provided

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778630/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2-no-such-file-or