# python error No such file or directory while installing a package

Tags: python, installation, pmdarima

I wanted to install a statistics package called pmdarima. I used

```
pip install pmdarima
```

I received the error message:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno
> 2] No such file or directory:
> ‘C:\Programs\Miniconda3_x64\jup369\Lib\site-packages\numpy\conftest.py

but I saw the file conftest.py in that directory!

Does anyone know what this error means?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your path might be too long. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778630/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2-no-such-file-or) link to question 54778630 for details. Try installing to a folder with a shorter path. [Here](https://exerror.com/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory/) is another guide that offers some more things to try.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).