# not updating the jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I find the following error when I try to update my "juypyter" notebook from version 6 to version 7
"ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\alifa\anaconda3\envs\tools\lib\site-packages\beautifulsoup4-4.11.2.dist-info\METADATA'"

Comment: [Please read through the answers for this question, It might help you solve your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778630/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2-no-such-file-or)

Comment: Why tag pandas?

Answer (score -1):

```
conda update conda
conda update pip
conda create -n jupyter_env python=3.8
conda activate jupyter_env
conda install jupyter
conda install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: I already have environment name "tools" i have installed jupyter 6 in tools. I want to update the same.

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.