# How to run and/or uninstall jupyter if installed in a custom directory?

Tags: python, windows, jupyter, target

So I am fairly new at programming with python using a work laptop with Windows 11 that I don't have admin rights for.

I tried to install jupyter using

```
pip install jupyter
```

This resulted in the "ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError:".
In all likelihood this problem occurred because the Windows Long Path support is not enabled. As I could not change that due to missing admin rights I decided to install jupyter in another, shorter path with

`pip install --target "[my_alternative_installation_path]" jupyter --no-user`

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778630/could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror-errno-2-no-such-file-or). With that, the installation process ran through without any errors.

Now I am wondering how I can actually run jupyter as starting it via command line does not work.

I tried it with

```
jupyter notebook
```

But I only get the error: "'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

I also tried running it via starting the jupyter-notebook.exe. But that only results in black (presumably cmd) window opening and directly closing again. After that, nothing happens.

After google search I added the jupyter installation directory to the PATH environment variable via PowerShell command:

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', "[installation_patch]", 'User')
```

But that did not change the behaviour.

Uninstalling jupyter does not work either:

```
pip uninstall jupyter
```

"WARNING: Skipping jupyter as it is not installed."

What did I miss?